# Trailing gargabe error when reading in JSON txt file data into Rstudio

Tags: r, json, data-analysis, txt

I'm trying to read in a JSON txt file but I keep running into the following error:

```
Error: parse error: trailing garbage
          .0-3.0","subID":"b428r"}] "rt","stimulus","response","trial_
                     (right here) ------^
```

Below you have part of the code (trying to run the final line produces the error).

```
## Read json file
raw_file <- paste0(inpath, "Json_raw_data.txt")
raw <- jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("\\}\\]\n\\[\\{", "},{", readChar(raw_file, file.info(raw_file)$size)))
raw <- raw[grepl("0\\.0-3\\.0-(1|2)", raw$internal_node_id), ]
```

Below you have a part of the raw JSON txt file:

```
[{"rt":89183,"response":{"P0_Q0":null,"age":"21","sex":"Female","handedness":"Left","education":"Postgraduate","languages":"English","P0_Q6":null},"accuracy":[],"trial_type":"survey","trial_index":0,"time_elapsed":89218,"internal_node_id":"0.0-0.0","subID":"b428r"}]
[{"view_history":[{"page_index":0,"viewing_time":10960},{"page_index":1,"viewing_time":8816},{"page_index":2,"viewing_time":8957},{"page_index":3,"viewing_time":1531},{"page_index":4,"viewing_time":1268}],"rt":31532,"trial_type":"instructions","trial_index":0,"time_elapsed":31534,"internal_node_id":"0.0-0.0-0.0","subID":"b428r"},{"success":true,"trial_type":"fullscreen","trial_index":1,"time_elapsed":39295,"internal_node_id":"0.0-0.0-1.0","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":2,"time_elapsed":39797,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.0","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":801,"stimulus":"<h1>basket</h1>","response":"e","task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":3,"time_elapsed":41799,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.0","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":4,"time_elapsed":42300,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.1","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>buelde</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":5,"time_elapsed":44301,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.1","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":6,"time_elapsed":44803,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.2","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>chebh</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":7,"time_elapsed":46804,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.2","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":8,"time_elapsed":47305,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.3","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>denonia</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":9,"time_elapsed":49306,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.3","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":10,"time_elapsed":49808,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.4","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>ezoch</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":11,"time_elapsed":51809,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.4","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":12,"time_elapsed":52310,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.5","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>flaudi</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":13,"time_elapsed":54312,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.5","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":14,"time_elapsed":54827,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.6","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":1017,"stimulus":"<h1>north</h1>","response":"e","task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":15,"time_elapsed":56828,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.6","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":16,"time_elapsed":57328,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.7","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>parede</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":17,"time_elapsed":59329,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.7","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":18,"time_elapsed":59831,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.8","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>ruva</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":19,"time_elapsed":61832,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.8","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":20,"time_elapsed":62333,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.9","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>sbover</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":21,"time_elapsed":64334,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.9","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":22,"time_elapsed":64835,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.10","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>taz</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":23,"time_elapsed":66837,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.10","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":24,"time_elapsed":67338,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.11","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>teage</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":25,"time_elapsed":69339,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.11","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":26,"time_elapsed":69841,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.12","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>voov</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":27,"time_elapsed":71842,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.12","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":28,"time_elapsed":72354,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.13","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":780,"stimulus":"<h1>whistle</h1>","response":"e","task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":29,"time_elapsed":74355,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.13","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":30,"time_elapsed":74856,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-0.14","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>xylk</h1>","response":null,"task":"practice","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":31,"time_elapsed":76857,"internal_node_id":"0.0-1.0-1.14","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":1708,"stimulus":"<strong> End of practice trials </strong><p style='color:Blue'><strong> Press the spacebar to begin the task </strong></p>","response":" ","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":32,"time_elapsed":78565,"internal_node_id":"0.0-2.0-0.0","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":33,"time_elapsed":79066,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-0.0","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>adhabu</h1>","response":null,"task":"familiarisation","stim_word":"adhabu","stim_type":"sw","stim_ans":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":34,"time_elapsed":81068,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-1.0","isCorrect":true,"subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>adhabu</h1>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":35,"time_elapsed":81068,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-2.0","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":36,"time_elapsed":81568,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-0.1","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>afya</h1>","response":null,"task":"familiarisation","stim_word":"afya","stim_type":"sw","stim_ans":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":37,"time_elapsed":83570,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-1.1","isCorrect":true,"subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>afya</h1>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":38,"time_elapsed":83575,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-2.1","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":39,"time_elapsed":84077,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-0.2","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":804,"stimulus":"<h1>agent</h1>","response":"e","task":"familiarisation","stim_word":"agent","stim_type":"en","stim_ans":"e","trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":40,"time_elapsed":86078,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-1.2","isCorrect":true,"subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>agent</h1>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":41,"time_elapsed":86084,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-2.2","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":42,"time_elapsed":86586,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-0.3","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>aibu</h1>","response":null,"task":"familiarisation","stim_word":"aibu","stim_type":"sw","stim_ans":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":43,"time_elapsed":88587,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-1.3","isCorrect":true,"subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>aibu</h1>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":44,"time_elapsed":88592,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-2.3","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":45,"time_elapsed":89093,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-0.4","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>alizeti</h1>","response":null,"task":"familiarisation","stim_word":"alizeti","stim_type":"sw","stim_ans":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":46,"time_elapsed":91094,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-1.4","isCorrect":true,"subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<h1>alizeti</h1>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":47,"time_elapsed":91099,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-2.4","subID":"b428r"},{"rt":null,"stimulus":"<p style=\"font-size:40px;\">+</p>","response":null,"trial_type":"html-keyboard-response","trial_index":48,"time_elapsed":91601,"internal_node_id":"0.0-3.0-0.5","subID":"b428r"}
```

Any ideas how to deal with this? Would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

I want to create a data frame that has the following columns to use for further analyses.

```
raw <- raw[, c("internal_node_id", "subID", "en_word", "is_target", "target", "lure", "sw_translation", "option_pressed", "is_correct", "num_options", "response", "rt")]
```